# Stop ngAfterContentInit from executing twice

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

I'm a bit confused as to why ngAfterContentInit is executing twice in this scenario. I've created a stripped-down version of our application to reproduce the bug. In short, I make use of a `*contentItem` to tag components which is then picked up by the `standard-layout` component for rendering. As soon as I follow this pattern, `demo`'s `ngAfterContentInit` is executed twice.

I placed the demo app on github which will reproduce the error: 
https://github.com/jVaaS/stackoverflow/tree/master/ngaftercontentinit

Otherwise here are the important bits:

buggy-app.dart:

```
@Component(
    selector: "buggy-app",
    template: """       
        <standard-layout>
            <demo *contentItem></demo>
        </standard-layout>
    """,
    directives: const [
        ContentItemDirective,
        StandardLayout,
        Demo
    ]
)
class BuggyApp implements AfterContentInit {

    @override
    ngAfterContentInit() {
        print(">>> ngAfterContentInit: BuggyApp");
    }
}
```

standard-layout.dart:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///
/// Standard Layout Component
/// <standard-layout></standard-layout>
///
@Component(
    selector: "standard-layout",
    template: """
        <div *ngFor="let item of contentItems ?? []">
            <template [ngTemplateOutlet]="item.template"></template>
        </div>
    """,
    directives: const [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ContentItem])
class StandardLayout implements AfterContentInit {

    @ContentChildren(ContentItemDirective)
    QueryList<ContentItemDirective> contentItems;

    @override
    ngAfterContentInit() {
        print(">>> ngAfterContentInit: StandardLayout");
    }

}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///
/// Content Item Directive
/// *contentItem
///
@Directive(selector: '[contentItem]')
class ContentItemDirective implements AfterContentInit {
    final ViewContainerRef vcRef;
    final TemplateRef template;
    final ComponentResolver componentResolver;

    ContentItemDirective(this.vcRef, this.template, this.componentResolver);

    ComponentRef componentRef;

    @override
    ngAfterContentInit() async {
        final componentFactory =
        await componentResolver.resolveComponent(ContentItem);
        componentRef = vcRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
        (componentRef.instance as ContentItem)
            ..template = template;
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///
/// Content Item Generator
///
@Component(
    selector: "content-item",
    host: const {
        '[class.content-item]': "true",
    },
    template: """
        <template [ngTemplateOutlet]="template"></template>
    """,
    directives: const [NgTemplateOutlet]
)
class ContentItem {
    TemplateRef template;
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

and finally `demo.dart`:

```
@Component(
    selector: "demo",
    template: "Hello World Once, but demo prints twice!")
class Demo implements AfterContentInit {

    @override
    ngAfterContentInit() {
        print(">>> ngAfterContentInit: Demo");
    }

}
```

`main.dart` doesn't have much in it:

```
void main() {
    bootstrap(BuggyApp);
}
```

When I run this, `Hello World` prints once as expected:
[image]

but when looking at the terminal:

[image]

So the `demo` component renders exactly once, but its `ngAfterContentInit` is being executed twice which causes havoc when your assumption is that it only gets executed once.

I've tried adding a hacky workaround, but it seems that component actually gets re-rendered twice:

```
int counter = 0;

@override
ngAfterContentInit() {

    if (counter == 0) {
        print(">>> ngAfterContentInit: Demo");
        counter++;
    }

}
```

Is this a bug in Angular or is there something I can do to prevent this?

`pubspec.yaml` in case it's needed:

```
name: bugdemo
version: 0.0.0
description: Bug Demo
environment:
  sdk: '>=1.13.0 <2.0.0'
dependencies:
  angular2: 3.1.0
  browser: ^0.10.0
  http: any
  js: ^0.6.0
  dart_to_js_script_rewriter: ^1.0.1
transformers:
- angular2:
    platform_directives:
    - package:angular2/common.dart#COMMON_DIRECTIVES
    platform_pipes:
    - package:angular2/common.dart#COMMON_PIPES
    entry_points: web/main.dart
- dart_to_js_script_rewriter
- $dart2js:
    commandLineOptions: [--enable-experimental-mirrors]
```

and `index.html` for good measure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Strange Bug</title>
</head>
<body>

    <buggy-app>
        Loading ...
    </buggy-app>

<script async src="main.dart" type="application/dart"></script>
<script async src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update**

So it was suggested that it might be that it only happens twice in dev-mode. I've done a `pub build` and ran the `index.html` which now contains `main.dart.js` in regular Chrome.

[image]

It's still executing twice, tried with `ngAfterViewInit` and that too executes twice.

Logged a bug in the meantime: 
https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/issues/478

Comment: if you are using `ngFor` to iterate for the child components, you cannot restrict the `ngAfterInit()` being called to a definite limit.

Comment: ok, what is the workaround to be able to render multiple restricted child components and only get a single `ngAfterContentInit` call ?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve. i'm confused. elaborate please

Comment: We're adding binders to certain events during `ngAfterInit` or `ngAfterContentInit` on top of a central event bus in the application. When it's called twice, those bindings are created twice causing things to happen twice instead of once.
The standard layout has many more things, `contentItem`, `navBarItem`, `footerItem`, `actionBarItem`, etc and when we're marking components with `<my-component *contentItem` so that it renders as a content item, the bindings to events / event listeners happen twice

Comment: The other thing we're doing is asking a provider to retrieve data from the server in `ngAfterContentInit`, data now gets loaded twice instead of once. What is the alternative to using an `ngFor` inside the `standard-layout` ?

Comment: are you available in teamviewer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148161/discussion-between-jan-vladimir-mostert-and-aravind).

Comment: It looks similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38787795/why-ngoninit-called-twice) (which refers to [this bug](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6782)). Could you handle [`ngAfterViewInit`](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) instead of `ngAfterContentInit`?

Comment: @ConnorsFan, I've seen that bug as well as the other post. I've stripped away almost all the code in order to narrow down the surface area of where the bug could occur. If there's an error in the HTML template, I'm overlooking it, have been through that template many times including with a hex editor and can't see anything obvious that's wrong with it.
Stripped down version of the source code:
https://github.com/jVaaS/stackoverflow/tree/master/ngaftercontentinit

Comment: @ConnorsFan actually `ngAfterViewInit` does exactly the same as `ngAfterContentInit` - it's also executing twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't seem like a bug.

Here is the generated code for `demo.dart`:
https://gist.github.com/matanlurey/f311d90053e36cc09c6e28f28ab2d4cd

```
void detectChangesInternal() {
  bool firstCheck = identical(this.cdState, ChangeDetectorState.NeverChecked);
  final _ctx = ctx;
  if (!import8.AppViewUtils.throwOnChanges) {
    dbg(0, 0, 0);
    if (firstCheck) {
      _Demo_0_2.ngAfterContentInit();
    }
  }
  _compView_0.detectChanges();
}
```

I was suspicious, so I changed your print message to include the `hashCode`:

```
@override
ngAfterContentInit() {
  print(">>> ngAfterContentInit: Demo $hashCode");
}
```

Then I saw the following:

> ngAfterContentInit: Demo 516575718
>
> ngAfterContentInit: Demo 57032191

Which means two *diffferent* instances of demo were alive, not just one emitting twice. I then added `StackTrace.current` to the constructor of demo to get a stack trace:

```
Demo() {
  print('Created $this:$hashCode');
  print(StackTrace.current);
}
```

And got:

> 0      Demo.Demo (package:bugdemo/demo.dart:11:20)
>   1      ViewBuggyApp1.build (package:bugdemo/buggy-app.template.dart:136:21)
>   2      AppView.create (package:angular2/src/core/linker/app_view.dart:180:12)
>   3      DebugAppView.create (package:angular2/src/debug/debug_app_view.dart:73:26)
>   4      TemplateRef.createEmbeddedView (package:angular2/src/core/linker/template_ref.dart:27:10)
>   5      ViewContainer.createEmbeddedView (package:angular2/src/core/linker/view_container.dart:86:43)

Which in turn said your component was being created by BuggyApp's template:

```
<standard-layout>
  <demo *contentItem></demo>
</standard-layout>
```

Closer. Kept digging.

I commented out `ContentItemDirective`, and saw Demo was now created once. I imagine you expected it not to be created at all due to `*contentItem`, so kept digging - and finally figured it out.

Your `StandardLayout` component creates templates:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of contentItems ?? []">
  <template [ngTemplateOutlet]="item.template"></template>
</div>
```

But so does your `ContentItemDirective` via *ComponentResolver*. I imagine you did not intend this. So I'd figure out what you were trying to do and address your issue by removing creating the component in one of these places.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe related to [In Angular2, why are there 2 times check for content and view after setTimeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34465301/in-angular2-why-are-there-2-times-check-for-content-and-view-after-settimeout)

Are you in dev mode ? The console tells you when the app bootstrap. In dev mode, Angular perfom the changeDetection twice, so it can detect side effects.

Comment: Are you suggesting that it only runs twice in dev mode? I've done a production build now using `pub build` and it seems that it does that in production as well.

Comment: It could have been that, but if that happened in prod mode... I don't know :/

Comment: AFAIK in Dart there is no devmode where change detection is run twice, but I'm not absolutely sure.